# Screen Blanking on console in Raspbian Stretch (Debian 9)

Tags: screen, power-management, terminal

I've burned the new Raspbian Stretch Lite image onto a SD Card and use this as my development system. I was used to turn off screen blanking on the console by changing the `BLANK_TIME` in `/etc/kbd/config` to `0`.

In Raspbian Stretch there is no such file and I cannot find an equivalent on the entire file system. So obviously the old behaviour has changed. kbd has been either removed or replaced.

What is the new way to disable screen blanking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either add `consoleblank=0` to the kernel command line or use this command:

```
TERM=linux setterm -blank 0 >> /etc/issue
```

(`/etc/issue` is displayed on each tty before login, this will disable the blanking)

Comment: There is also a very detailed answer to this topic at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/154388).